# Reading strings from file. QTextStream does not read file

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore

I need to read strings from foo.txt:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QTextStream>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    QFile file("foo.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        return 1;
    QStringList stringList;
    QTextStream textStream(&file);
    textStream.readLine();
    while (!textStream.atEnd())
        stringList << textStream.readLine();

    file.close();

    qDebug() << stringList;

    return 0;
}
```

[image: outPut]

file opened, but textStream always empty.

Comment: It works for me on Linux running it at the command line. It prints out `("Good day")` which is what I would expect as you don't put the first line into the string list.

Comment: Problem is: foo.txt in project folder, but .exe in build folder. Can I include foo.txt in .exe for do not worry about" Where is that file?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment it would appear that the executable is simply not finding the file as they are in different locations. There are a variety of ways to solve this and it depends on what the final use case is meant to be. Here are some ways you can solve the issue:

- hard code in the path to the file (relative or absolute)
- move the file to be in the same directory as the executable
- use a command line option to tell the executable where the file is
- use an environment variable to tell the executable where to look

For testing either of the first two options are quick and easy but you will probably want something better than that if you intend to take things further.

Comment: @StasShakirov: it is not specific to Android. What Troubadour is trying to write is that you need to evaluate these options and pick the best for your scenario. You have not shared enough information to help with that.